# how to print a string in a textview?

Tags: java, android, json, textview

I am new to all of this android programming. After working out a few codes, I get the following string called ipString. I would like to display the string in a textview.

Here is what I have for now.

What should I add to make it work?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.d("Rami","Rami");
    DefaultHttpClient   httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://jsonip.com");
    // Depends on your web service
    httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

    InputStream inputStream = null;
    String result = null;
    try {
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);           
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        inputStream = entity.getContent();
        // json is UTF-8 by default
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            sb.append(line + "\n");

        }
        result = sb.toString();
        JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);
        String ipString = jObject.getString("ip");
        Log.d("ip", ipString);
    } catch (Exception e) { 
        // Oops
    }
    finally {
        try{if(inputStream != null)inputStream.close();}catch(Exception squish){}
    }

    TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
```

Comment: [`myTextView.setText();`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(java.lang.CharSequence)<=link.

Comment: so i add myTextView.setText(ipString); ?

Comment: What happened after you followed, read and tried what is detailed in the link I provided?

Comment: once again, i am new to all this. I don't even know where to start looking in the link that you just posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use setText() this way:

```
TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
myTextView.setText(ipString);
```

Anyway you should put those two lines inside your try, that way it would only print the String if the HTTP Request was successful.

```
try {
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);           
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        inputStream = entity.getContent();
        // json is UTF-8 by default
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            sb.append(line + "\n");

        }
        result = sb.toString();
        JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);
        String ipString = jObject.getString("ip");
        Log.d("ip", ipString);

        TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
        myTextView.setText(ipString);

    } catch (Exception e) { 
        // Oops
    }
    finally {
        try{if(inputStream != null)inputStream.close();}catch(Exception squish){}
    }
```

BTW you should really read (and try to understand) the documentation and learn how to use your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Use `setText()` it will display your response text.

```
TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
myTextView.setText(ipString);
```

Comment: that's what i did and i get a red line under ipString

Comment: @RamiYahia: you need to learn how to use the tools you're using my friend. Hover your mouse over the red lines and let G know what it says

Answer (score 0):

use setText() method like this :

```
String yourstringvalue;
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textviewID);

text.setText(yourstringvalue);
```